# Vaadin7 themes in Websphere Portal

Tags: vaadin, portlet, websphere-portal

I would deploy my Vaadin custom themes in Websphere and reference them in some vaadin portlets deployed in Websphere Portal.
I'm using Websphere 8.5 and Vaadin 7. I found a lot of topic about the Tomcat and Liferay combination but nothing usefull for Websphere.

I also tried to set the vaadin.resources.path variable in the 'WP PortletContainerService' in Resources>Resource Environment>Resource Environment Providers and I set a resource with name 'std.portalcontext.vaadin.resources.path' but I can't see it in UI.

​Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Setting that property on the portletcontainerservice is not going to help you because it is not one of the properties that the WebSphere Portal container is going to recognize as a property.  I think you may have to do something like this https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/2732876/2732875 specifically these https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=Developing+portlets+for+the+Websphere+Portal+Server

The main thing to do is this 
In the portlet tag you have to set a value for the portlet-class. For this simple we can use the default Vaadin portlet class com.vaadin.server.VaadinPortlet; you also have to name you UI class as a portlet init parameter.

To let WPS find the Vaadin javascript and theme resources you have to use the portlet init parameter vaadin.resources.path. The value PORTLET_CONTEXT is a Vaadin constant value that makes the vaadin resources available in the portlets resource path.

Run the Maven build with clean package as goals and deploy the created war file in the portal administration. Create a blank portal page and add your portlet to the page. Your "Click me" portlet should look like this:

Comment: Please post the gist of what "this" is into your answer. External links tend to rot, at which point this answer will be useless to future readers.